# Swift 3 - Como fazer com que um alerta seja exibido após e tela carregar?

Tags: swift, swift-3

Olá estou construindo um app que necessita que um alerta seja apresentado assim que o Usuário acessar a tela.

Pra isso eu fiz uma ViewController e vinculei a view que esta sendo acessada

```
class EducacaoController : UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Atenção!", message: "oi", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let acaoAvançar = UIAlertAction(title: "Avançar", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(acaoAvançar)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Aparentemente acredito que esteja certo, porem sempre apresenta a mensagem no console:

2017-06-09 11:30:53.377951-0300 IssoEBrasil[599:216652] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde Matheus :) 
Coloquei o seu código aqui e realmente esta dando essa mensagem...
Para não enrolar muito vou passar como faço:

```
func Mensagem(_ strTitle : NSString, strBody: NSString, delegate: AnyObject?)
    {

        let valert : UIAlertView = UIAlertView();
        valert.message  = strBody as String;
        valert.title    = strTitle as String;
        valert.delegate = delegate;
        valert.addButton(withTitle: "OK");
        valert.show();

    }
```

Para usar é molinho molinho :)

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        Mensagem("Ola", strBody: "VAI", delegate: nil);



    }
```

Espero que seja isso que você esta querendo.. :) 
Abraços

Comment: Obrigado Ricardo o/, resolveu

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde (novamente :) ) Matheus..
Outra forma de fazer o que você quer é adicionando o viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Atenção!", message: "oi", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let acaoAvançar = UIAlertAction(title: "Avançar", style: .default, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(acaoAvançar)



        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

É o seu código só que em um lugar diferente.
Se você testar verá que toda vez que a tela APARECE a mensagem é disparada sem o erro mencionado..
Coloquei isso pois esse poderia ser sua necessidade..
Abraços.. :)